# Most efficent way to implement a function in class Base

Tags: c++, windows, inheritance, callback

I have a base class Base and two derived classes DerivedA,  DerivedB

```
class Base
{
};

class DerivedA: public Base 
{
   CallbackTypeA callA; // call back function pointer of type CallbackTypeA.
};

class DerivedB : public Base 
{
   CallbackTypeB callB; // call back function pointer of type CallbackTypeB.
};
```

Can anybody tell me which is the most efficent way to implement a function in class Base
that checks a particular condition for  callA or callB depending on which object calls it?
Due to some current constraints, I dont want to use virtual function

Comment: why dont you use virtual function?

Comment: Question is not clear. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: What are you doing to solve this problem right now? Or is the question really, _"I don't know how to do this!"_? The difference is important! What do you mean by efficient, incidentally?

Comment: Due to some current constraints, I dont want to use virtual function.

Comment: Virtual functions are the natural, easy and efficient way to do that. If you don't want to use them you will have to resort to ugly hacks.

Comment: @Rook The real difference is that whether you want me to a ask question for you answer or you want to answer this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of 2 ways which will work but I still advice to use Virtual Function if possible.

A.
have a pointer to a function in the base class, and in the constructor of the derived class set it to point to the correct function. Then the base class can call it. But this is basically doing what the virtual function mechanism does.

B.
have an Enum in the base class which has a value for each derived class, each derived class will set this Enum to it's own value. in the Base class then you can check this value and cast to the right class and call the correct function. But this is very very bad practice cause the Base class need to know about the derived class.

Again, I don't know what is the issue that makes you don't want to use the virtual functions. but I think you should rethink it...

Comment: +1 mainly for the last sentence. I can't think of any mechanism that does not revolve around whay you present, and both are far inferior to virtual functions.

Answer (score 1):

Use a virtual function and/or (depending on the actual structure of the code) `typeid`. In most cases virtual functions are likely to be the best solution overall: code legibility, less prone to bugs etc.